# Event aggregator pattern vs delegate/event

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I want to create a simple event aggregator with named events, eg:

```
Hub.AddListener(string Name, Action<int> Callback);
Hub.Invoke(string Name, int Message);
```

But I am not able to figure out a solution using delegate, event and dictionary, neither `Dictionary<string, EventHandler>` nor `Dictionary<string, Action<int>>` allow me to `+=` more subscribers onto the same event.

So should I use something like `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` and side step event/delegate altogether?

Comment: In short: I can't find a way to put delegate or event in a dictionary, because it either remembers the value type (with `Dictionary<string, delegate>`) or it require me to wrap the event with a lambda (with `Dictionary<string, Action<T>>`), in neither case I could use `+=`.

Comment: delegates are not value types, they're reference types.  Additionally `Action<T>` is not a lambda, it's just a delegate type, just like any other.  You can use a lambda to create an instance of a delegate of any type, just as you can use a method group to create an instance of a delegate of any type.

Comment: @Servy ok I figure out exactly why: sure `Dictionary<string, delegate>` holds a reference of delegate, but when I take the delegate from Dictionary and do `delegate += callback`, it becomes a new reference, and the dictionary itself is not updated. I have to do `dic[name] = delegate`. doh.

Comment: I updated my answer with a multicast delegate. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a multicast delegate:

```
public class Hub
{        
    private Dictionary<string, Action<int>> _events = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>();

    public void AddListener(string name, Action<int> callback)
    {
        if (!_events.ContainsKey(name))
            _events.Add(name, callback);
        else
        {
            var handler = _events[name];
            _events[name] = handler + callback;                
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(string name, int message)
    {
        if (_events.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            var handler = _events[name];
            handler(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
 Hub hub = new Hub();
 hub.AddListener("one", delegate (int a) { Console.WriteLine("First " + a); });
 hub.AddListener("one", delegate (int a) { Console.WriteLine("Second " + a); });
 hub.Invoke("one", 5);
```

Output:

```
First 5
Second 5
```

You can read more about it here:

[How to: Combine Delegates (Multicast Delegates)(C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates)

Comment: Thx, but it's essentially the same as Dictionary<string, List<object>> as you have to loop over the List to invoke each callbacks.

Comment: @bitinn: I misunderstood your original question. I have updated my answer. Please take another look.